# devise gem flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

if i am using the devise gem with rails, how do i make the flash messages appear only when theres content inside of it.

does rails have an easy way to do this or do i manually need to do it in jquery?

currently im using twitter bootstrap v2 and it has them built in by default. here is the best jquery i could come up with by the way, im not sure how this could be refactored better (although i definitely know it could be). I had to do it like this because i have an 'x' inside the `<p>` flash

```
if($('.alert-success').clone().children().remove().end().text() != "") {
    $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
  }
  if($('.alert-error').clone().children().remove().end().text() != "") {
    $('.alert-error').fadeIn();
  }
```

**EDIT:**
My layout contains:

```
<p class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= alert %></p>
```

Comment: What's in your Rails layout where the flashes get output?

Comment: <p class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= notice %></p>
      <p class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= alert %></p>

Comment: So what you're asking is: How can you output `<p class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= notice %></p>` only `if` there's some content in `notice`?

Comment: well i know there are a lot of ways to do it (an if statement with embedded ruby), i just wondered what the 'rails way' to do it is, it has a lot of magic built in i wasnt sure if this is one of those times

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, there's no real magic here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No special methods here, I'd simply control how those tags are output with a surrounding `if`:

```
<% if notice %><p class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= notice %></p><% end %>
<% if alert %><p class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><%= alert %></p><% end %>
```