# Rails: notice: messages won't disappear Using rails_layout gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, rails-flash, rails-composer

I'm not sure if this is a bug or what, but the notice messages are not disappearing and I have looked at a bunch of other examples, none of them explain my case:
like these:
[Why flash message won't disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613952/why-flash-message-wont-disappear)

[rails 4 -- flash notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566072/rails-4-flash-notice)

[Rails flash notice won't go away in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450623/rails-flash-notice-wont-go-away-in-safari)

[devise gem flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428864/devise-gem-flash-messages)

I used the [***Rails_Composer***](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) and I promised myself not to use it again, because it just caused me a nightmare

This is what I have loaded in my files:

```
application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require wiselinks
//= require_tree .

application.css.scss

/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
framework_and_overrides.css.scss
@import "bootstrap.min";
```

and as the [***Rails_Composer***](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) generates the files, this is what we have in the layout:

```
_messages.html.eb

<%# Rails flash messages styled for Bootstrap 3.0 %>
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

any idea how to fix this mess ?